# Excel Power Query - M Language - Reference to "ThisTable"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, power-query

As total Power Query newbie I'm trying to create Power Query function which adds an Index Column to the table. But I'm struggling with passing a table reference to [`AddIndexColumn` function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-addindexcolumn)

What I tried:

```
let
    Func = () => Table.AddIndexColumn(Table, "Index", 1, 1)
in
    Func
```

This gives an Expression.Error (Table is not recognized or something - It's shown in system language which is not EN)

---

```
let
    Func = (T as table) => Table.AddIndexColumn(T, "Index", 1, 1)
in
    Func
```

Then use `Invoke Custom Function` in "MyTable" and in popup is dropdown list with all other tables except "MyTable" which is the table where I want to add the IndexColumn.

---

Is there some limitation, or I'm missing something?

Thanks for help!

PS: I know this function does not have a real-life usage and there are different (better) ways how to add an index column. Consider it as Proof of Concept thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, function for adding an index column is not meant for `Invoke Custom Function`. Because it creates a new column and invoke the function for each cell in this column -> it could create thousands new columns.

But a function witch such functionality could be written and then used in a query code. Notice that `Table` object just provides [Table related functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-functions) here, it is not connected to the data table itself. The data table reference must be provided by `Table.function` parameter.

### Function code

```fs
let
    AddIndexColumn=(Source as table, IndexColName as text) => Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, IndexColName, 0, 1)

in
    AddIndexColumn
```

### How to use function in a query

```fs
let
    Source = ...
    SourceIndex = AddIndexColumn(Source, Name)
in
    SourceIndex
```

**NOTE:** Refference to `Source` is not availible in GUI dropdown list, it must be written manually in the `Advanced Editor`!